# How to check a URI with bool or if in C#

Tags: c#, url, uri

I have to check if a URI matches "https://example.com" and if it matches navigate to another Website.

I tried two methods:

```
Uri uriResult;
bool result = Uri.TryCreate("https://expample.com/index",UriKind.Absolute, out uriResult)
    && uriResult.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttps;
if (result)
{
    webBrowser1.Navigate("https://expample.com/home");
}
```

Method 2:

```
if (Uri.IsWellFormedUriString("https://expample.com/index", UriKind.Absolute))
{ 
  webBrowser1.Navigate("https://expample.com/home")
}
```

But always when I start the program the `webBrowser1` loads "https://expample.com/home" and refreshing the how time doesn't matter which website the `webBrowser1` Show.

It seems to me that the if function is ignoring the `(result)`/ the URL (second code)

Comment: what exactly is the webBrowser1 object?

Comment: Its a From object I think.
    `private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        { //*the code i wrote in my question* }`

Answer (score 0):

```
        string forCheckin = uriResult.ToString();
        if (forCheckin == "https://example.com")
        {
            //navigation to page
        }
```

If I understood you correctly this will do it.